# Why is my MatPlotLib split axes graph not appearing?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I tried to create a graph side by side using matplotlib.

I don't get any errors when I run my code, instead, I just get a blank window from MatPlotLib.

Here's the link I used for my CSV.
https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EGSPTSE/history?p=%5EGSPTSE

Previously, I have also created a graph that overlayed the two lines(which works as intended), but they are not displaying as seperate graphs, which is what I am trying to do with my current code.

I tried this video for information in creating these graphs, but I can't replicate the graph shown in the video even when I copy the code.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-2AMr95nUDw

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as mpl
import pandas as pd

data_better = pd.read_csv('What.csv')
# print(data_better.head()) #I used this part to find out what the headers were for x values
# print(data_better.columns[::])

mpl.axes([15000, 17000, 20000, 23000])
mpl.title("Open Values")
mpl.plot(data_better["Date"], data_better["Open"])
mpl.ylabel("Money")
mpl.axes([15000, 17000, 20000, 23000])
mpl.title("Close Values")
mpl.plot(data_better["Date"], data_better["Close"])
mpl.ylabel("Money")
mpl.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. [`pyplot.axes`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.axes.html) accepts 4-tuple of floats in normalized `(0, 1)` units to place the axes. You can look at examples in [Make Room For Ylabel Using Axesgrid](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/axes_grid1/make_room_for_ylabel_using_axesgrid.html) to learn using it.
2. If you want to plot two plots in one figure, you need use different axes

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data_better = pd.read_csv('What.csv')

figure, (axes1, axes2) = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)

axes1.set_title("Open Values")
axes1.plot(data_better["Date"], data_better["Open"])
axes1.set_ylabel("Money")

axes2.set_title("Close Values")
axes2.plot(data_better["Date"], data_better["Close"])
axes2.set_ylabel("Money")

plt.show()
```